# (Angular 10 ) Test directive with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, angular2-directives

I created a directive to detect when I click outside of an element. When it happens I emit a boolean. How can I test this using Jasmine?

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
 
@Directive({
  selector: '[ocClickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
 
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }
 
  @Output() public ocClickOutside: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
 
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  public onMouseEnter(targetElement: any): void {
    const clickedInside = this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
    if (!clickedInside) {
      this.ocClickOutside.emit(null);
    }
  }
 
 
}
```